# finite group $G$ that has an element $x$ of order 10 and another element $y$ of order 6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If I have a finite group $G$ that has an element $x$ of order 10 and another element $y$ of order 6, is there anything special about G that we can infer? Would the order of $G$ be 30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't necessarily say that it is $30$, but for a finite group $G$, the order of an element divides the order of the group. Thus, you can say that $6||G|$ and $10||G|$, so...?

Comment: the order of G is a multiple of lcm(6,10)?

Comment: Right, and that is $30$, so you were close.

Comment: Great thanks! So, we can just say it's a multiple of 30 not that it is 30 or 60, but just some multiple

Comment: Correct - and any multiple is possible (just take a group with 30 elements that has elements of orders 6 and 10, and take a direct product with another group with $N$ elements, the resulting group has $30N$ elements).

Comment: @RobMoonKard For another easy example, take $S_{10}$.